# AS400 signoff from Java program

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

I am new to as400-java integration.
I have created a Web-app which calls a Java program at backend which in turn calls a AS400 through jt400 api. 
I want to keep a log-off button/hyperlink which will sign off the current user.
What I observed is,when a user is logging in the first time, log off is not happening unless I restart my Web-app server(Tomcat) [which cannot be done every time of course! ],even though I did this
in my java program :

```
finally{
  as400System.disconnectAllServices(); 
  }
```

when I am done, still that user is logged on , the next time I hit my web app url.

I have tried to call the "signoff" command of AS400 through a separate program, but that command call is returning "false":

```
 CommandCall command = new CommandCall(as400);
 boolean result= command.run("signoff"); ....
 System.out.println(result);...
 AS400Message[] messageList = command.getMessageList();
  for (AS400Message message : messageList){
   System.out.println(message.getText());
  }
```

Above code prints this:

```
false..
Command SIGNOFF not allowed in this setting. 
Errors occurred in command.
```

Any suggestions how to handle signing off in such a scenario?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to log on? How do you know that a user remains logged on? (Absence of a logon prompt isn't sufficient since credentials might be cached.) Also just FYI, SIGNOFF is exclusively for a terminal session, so we'll need to determine appropriate logoff for whatever your logon is.

Comment: I am using jt400 jar. It comes with an inbuilt swing type of pop-up which prompts me to log on, if I only hit the AS400 url(without login credentials). Hence I have no java code of my own for login from Web app side. And yes, caching factor came to my mind too, but where and how it is caching I am not able to figure out here @user2338816

Answer (score 1):

The [Javdocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400.html) say that `disconnectAllServices()`

> Disconnects all services. All socket connections associated with this object will be closed. **The signon information is not changed, and connection properties remain frozen.**

I think you want `resetAllServices()`

> Disconnects all services, and clears the sign-on information. This intent of this method is to "wipe the slate clean" for this AS400 object, enabling connection properties to be subsequently reset.

Comment: Thanks Charles, but resetAllServices() does not seem to solve my problem. I added both
   as400System.disconnectAllServices();
   as400System.resetAllServices(); in my finally block. Still the same issue. I am not getting the login prompt(that I am getting on Tomcat restart) and logged-in user is remaining logged in somehow.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured out one step of it. The default sign-on prompt of jt400 api comes with a checkbox "Default Id" . If I don't check it, it's asking for a re-login when I am nullifying the com.ibm.as400.access.AS400 object in my java logout code. So thats allright.

But still issue remains, when that checkbox is checked, I am having to restart the web server.

Comment: Update: I have opted for a workaround. I have set com.ibm.as400.access.AS400 object's setGuiAvailable(false). Now I am not getting the sign-on pop up. I have generated my own Login web page. On incorrect attempt jt400 throws a AS400SecurityException , which am handling and getting the error message from the exception object.